# "--numeric-suffixes" does not allow an argument with "split"

Tags: arguments, split

I'm trying to use the split command for a shell script I'm writing and I want to use the --numeric-suffixes flag in order to start my file count from 1. I try:

```
split -a 1 -l 2 --numeric-suffixes=1 test.txt
```

However the output I get is

```
split: option `--numeric-suffixes' doesn't allow an argument
```

Not sure how to fix this but I've tried other flags like --additional-suffix and that doesn't work either. Also as an fyi if I don't include the -- flags my command runs correctly. Any help would be appreciated (I'm a unix newb, so be gentle please)

---

`split --version` outputs `split (GNU coreutils) 5.97`

`split --help` says `-d, --numeric-suffixes use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic`.

Comment: The latest version of coreutils is 8.31, and `split` in there supports giving an argument to `--numeric-suffixes`.  Your Unix is using an ancient coreutils package (2006?).  What Unix are you using (`uname -a`)?

Comment: oh thanks for the clarification. Do you know what command I can run to update it?

Comment: Not without knowing what Unix you are running.  Also, if coreutils is that old, then it's likely that a lot of other packages are also outdated.  Are you the admin of this system?

Comment: no just started at new job actually. unix is: Linux x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: In that case, you should talk to your local system administrator(s) and see whether they can upgrade your system. If it is as I suspect, it's not only the coreutils package that needs upgrading, but many other packages, including security fixes and kernel upgrades. This might be non-trivial for someone new to Linux to do, depending on your system's configuration.

Comment: will do. Thanks @Kusalananda appreciate the quick help!

Comment: I'm leaving the question open, with the view that someone may know a way to work around the missing functionality in `split`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case (`-l 2`) a workaround is to add exactly two lines (empty or not, it doesn't matter much) before the actual content of `test.txt`. You can do this on the fly.

Then `split -a 1 -l 2 --numeric-suffixes` will generate files starting from `x0`. This 0th file will contain the extra lines. Remove the file. Remaining `x*` files will be as if you used `--numeric-suffixes=1`.

```
(printf '\n\n'; cat test.txt) | split -a 1 -l 2 --numeric-suffixes
rm x0
```

---

The approach can be generalized to match different `-l` and different desired `--numeric-suffixes=`. You need to calculate how many lines to add before `split` and which files to remove after.

One can generate any sane number of lines with `yes '' | head -n "$number"`. One can remove any sane number of files with a `for` loop.

---

<sup>As noted in comments, if your `split` is so old it doesn't support `--numeric-suffixes=` then you should consider upgrading.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

That split version was released in 2006-06-24

You might consider updating to >= 8.16 (2012-03-26), which does support an argument to --numeric-suffixes